# Clipping OpenStreetMap basemap using QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, openstreetmap, clip, masking

I'm using QGIS, and I am trying to clip my metro region data to only show the OSM basemap in the the metro region, using this thread:
[Clipping OSM Standard Basemap using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381342/clipping-osm-standard-basemap-using-qgis)

I created an inverted polgygon shapefile to mask the metro area, but when it does so it also masks the OSM layer beneath it.  The screenshots are from toggling this layer on and off.

How would I get the metro region to appear, along with the base map beneath it?

Do I need to create a separate shapefile of the OSM basemap I need in order to be able to work with it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does your mask layer have the correct geometry (that you want to use as mask)?

Comment: You need a layer with a polygon that covers exactely the region of the metro region. Duplicate the layer with the colored polygons that can be seen on screenshot 2 and set this to inverted polygons. I can't see what the mask layer admin_level_4 consists of, but probably the problem is there: how many and which features does it contain?