# Clipping OSM does not work

Tags: qgis

I am new to QGIS and I am trying to clip the OpenStreetMap layer but when I try the GDAL "clip raster by mask layer" it gives me the following error:

> ERROR 4:
> `type=xyz&url=https://tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png&zmax=19&zmin=0'
> does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a
> supported dataset name.
>
> Process returned error code 2

Can someone explain what's going wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: Same question as here, see the answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/381347/88814 - Quick answer: you can't clip from OSM XYZ-tiles. What you can do is masking some areas of the OSM basemap.

Comment: ahh that makes sense, Thanks!