# Showing data only within certain area in QGIS

Tags: qgis, area, filter

I've downloaded some data-files online and loaded these into QGIS. This is data from the whole country,  so in the map the country is fully covered with the data visually. However, I only want to see the data within two provinces (a demarcated area).

Does anyone know how to only show the data within that area? I cannot simply delete data outside of that area, because editing the data-file is not permitted.

[image: Screenshot of the country with data projected on it]

Comment: Do you have polygons(boundaries) of two provinces? If so, use [Clip](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#clip) tool.

Comment: Do you data have an province ( or equivalent) field ? If yes it's easy to filter

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/381347/88814

Comment: If you download the data what prevent you to edit ? after all it's not like if you where working with the original data

Answer (score 6):

The easiest non-editing way to do this would be with the QGIS plugin Mask which you can get from the standard repository (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mask/)

Format your whole-country data in whatever way you want as a first step. Then you need a polygon shapefile showing your specific area. Select the polygons representing your study area and open the mask tool, follow the instructions. It will create a new layer masking out everything else, and it can be set up to also mask out labels.

Answer (score 5):

If you have the polygons(boundaries) of two provinces, use [Clip](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#clip) tool. By doing this, you get a new layer.

But you want to visualize only two provinces data in the map, open Layer Styling Panel (F7), play around with "Blending mode" options under "Layer Rendering".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Get a polygon with administrative units of your area of interest (e.g. from https://gadm.org/)
2. Select the two provinces you're interested in.
3. Right click layer > [Zoom to Selection](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#zooming-and-panning).

To permanently save this extent, create a [`New Spatial Bookmark`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#spatial-bookmarks) (click the icon or use shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>). In the browser panel, you now find the extent under the name you saved it. Clicking on it will immediately zoom to this extent.